# How to enable config features menu in WSO2 Enterprice Integrator on Windows?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I would enable the hl7 transport on WSO2 Enterprice Integrator. The documentation says to use the feature manager under configuration->features menu; but this menu item not exist for EI 6.0.0 on Windows (or so it seems)

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have installed on the same machine WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 and the feature manager menu is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened an issue on https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/ and this is the [answer](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/271#issuecomment-285262726)!. I hope it is of help to someone.
This is a temporary alternative solution waiting for fix...